# Detecting $k$-affinoid spaces by vanishing cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry, berkovich-geometry

The property of being an affine scheme can be tested against all quasi-coherent sheaves in the following sense: a noetherian scheme $X$ is affine iff $H^i(X,\mathcal{F}) = 0$ for all quasi-coherent $\mathcal{F}$ and all $i > 0$. This is e.g. Theorem III.3.7 of Hartshorne.

Now, let $X = \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{A})$ be a $k$-affinoid space in the sense of Chapter 2 of Berkovich, where $k$ is a non-archimedean field. 
In this setting, there doesn't seem to be a notion of a quasi-coherent sheaf in the literature, though we of course have coherent ones.

My question is the following: given a $k$-analytic space $X$, is there an analogous cohomological criterion for detecting whether $X$ is $k$-affinoid?

Comment: Brian Conrad's notes ( http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/aws.pdf ) seems to suggest the answer is no: see remark 3.1.7 on p.24 of the linked document.

Comment: @user31814 Thanks for pointing out this remark! The example that Brian Conrad cites is featured in [Liu](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~qliu/articles/cras.pdf), and it is example of a rigid analytic space (in the sense of Tate) $X$, which is not affinoid, such that $H^i(X,\mathcal{F}) = 0$ for $\mathcal{F}$ coherent. But this is not to say that we couldn't "enlarge the class of test sheaves" in a reasonable way to be able to test cohomologically whether this $X$ is affinoid. This is what I am wondering: whether such a criterion exists.

Comment: By analogy, as in [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153523/does-vanishing-of-cohomology-of-locally-free-sheaves-imply-affiness-of-scheme) question, there are schemes $X$ such that $H^i(X,\mathcal{F}) = 0$ for all locally free $\mathcal{F}$, but if we enlarge the class of test sheaves to all coherent ones, then we can test for affine-ness in this way.

Comment: You can have a look at Conrad's paper "Relative ampleness in rigid geometry" (Annales de l’institut Fourier, 2006, http://aif.cedram.org/aif-bin/fitem?id=AIF_2006__56_4_1049_0) and especially section 2.1 for a definition of quasi-coherent sheaves in rigid geometry (as sheaves that are locally direct limits of coherent sheaves). With this definition, there exist quasi-coherent sheaves with non-vanishing cohomology on affinoid spaces (see example 2.1.6, due to Gabber).